# I want to make a mug cake, can I use hot chocolate mix instead of cocoa?

Tags: substitutions, cake, chocolate, cocoa

Unfortunately, I do not have any cocoa powder left. If I use Cadbury's hot chocolate mix, would it give me the same effect?

Comment: The issue with hot chocolate mix is the lack of cocoa and high amounts of sugar.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely want to use cocoa powder if you can...but...

I've done it in a pinch. It's not as good as cocoa powder though because hot chocolate mix is usually also sugar & sometimes powdered milk. But it's still something to fix a chocolate craving when you don't have much else in the cupboard.

I've added hot chocolate mix to waffle mix/pancake mix and always found it delicious, though of course not as chocolate-y as with pure cocoa powder.

Answer (score 4):

I have been in the same situation as you and I used hot chocolate mix and it worked just fine.

But if you want a stronger taste, use cocoa powder. When I used hot chocolate mix, my cake was a bit bland and not very chocolatey - although it might have just been the hot chocolate mix I was using.

Answer (score 3):

I have used hot chocolate mix instead of cocoa powder... As state earlier it is usually a blend of cocoa, sugar and milk powder... so, you need to adjust the sugar levels. However, also be aware that some of the new style hot chocolate mixes that want to emulate the milky froth of a hot chocolate made with an espresso machine also contain a frothing agent... The "rise" I got from this mix was very "interesting". (and the mess was unwanted)

Another substitute I found for cocoa, is chocolate pudding mix, or even on one occasion a chocolate pudding cup; this produces a very rich, moist chocolate mug cake, or a really nice enhancement for a packet chocolate mix.

Comment: You can probably use the nutrition information line for sugars to get an estimate of how much sugar your hot chocolate mix replaces, and increase the quantity to get the same amount of non-sugar (assumed to be cocoa).

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend using cocoa powder as it gives it that nice rich chocolaty flavoring.However, if you don't have cocoa powder use hot chocolate mix but keep the sugar down on your original mix as it will become too sweet. Also, the colour of the cake will not be as dark as it would be with cocoa powder